# Geocoding addresses from Excel in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, geocoding

I have a set of addresses in Belgium in Excel and I would want to geocode/transform them in coordinates in order to be able ta visualize them in QGIS 3.4. Does someone know how I could do?

Comment: How many records, do you have  to process?

Answer (score 2):

There is a QGIS plugin called MMQGIS that has a function to geocode a CSV file using either OpenStreetMap/Nominatim or Google (if you have a Google API key).

Answer (score 2):

### For QGIS versions QGIS 3.20 and higher

[Starting from QGIS 3.20](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-nominatim-geocoder-integration) it is possible to geocode addresses to coordinates by means of the native tool ["Batch Nominatim geocoder"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#batch-nominatim-geocoder), can be found under Vector General in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

**Step 1.** Prepare your input CSV file which includes an address field i.e. is a concatenation of fields e.g. street, house number, postal code, city, state, country. (Some attributes are optional)

Let's assume there is a CSV file called *'test.csv'*, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 2.** Drag&Drop the CSV file into QGIS. Make sure the right encoding was chosen i.e. UTF-8

[image: step_1]

**Step 3.** Apply the "Batch Nominatim geocoder" and press <kbd>Run</kbd>

[image: step_2]

**Step 4.** Get the final output

[image: result]